# ¿Cómo tomar los valores de entrada de un CNY70 digitalmente (1 y 0)? Pic C Compiler

Tags: c, ccs

Estoy realizando un proyecto con el sensor CNY70 y quiero testear su entrada de manera **digital** en Pic C Compiler.

**1.** Me dijeron que necesito configurar el sensor para que me dé los valores de entrada en 0 y 1 **¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?**

**2.** Una vez realizada esa configuración, me recomendaron utilizar la función **bit_test** pero
no estoy muy segura de cómo aplicarla.

**Esta es la condición que tengo, después del if tendría que utilizar la función "bit_test":**

```
if(cny70==1); // Si el CNY70 capta un objeto
```

**Yo supongo que tendría que cambiarlo de esta manera:**

```
if(bit_test(cny70)==1); // Si el CNY70 capta un objeto
```

¿Estaré en lo correcto? Saludoss

Comment: Qué dice la documentación del sensor `CNY70` y el Pic al respecto?

Comment: Entiendo que con Arduino podes usar `digitalRead`. No sé cómo se hace en un PIC.

Comment: @AndresGardiol Vi que todos los pines asignados a los sensores son digitales, aunque hay uno que en vez de **"digital I/O"**  dice **"digital input"**. No se que si hay mucha diferencia. Con respecto al sensor, miré la documentación de Vishay y no especifica nada sobre configuración.

Comment: No encontré mucho sobre configurar específicamente este sensor, cambié la función `if(bit_test(cny70)==1);` por `if(input(cny70)==1);`.

Comment: Te recomendaría que agregues la documentación que estás consultando a tu pregunta (con el botón [edit]) así alguien podría revisarla y tratar de ayudarte